# RSS feed limit items

Tags: php, rss

How can i limit the items from my RSS-feed? (Example: 5 items).  I hope someone can help me with this code.

```
<?php
$url = "LINK TO RSS";
$rss = simplexml_load_file($url);
if($rss) 
{
    $items = $rss->channel->item;
    foreach($items as $item)
    {
        $title = $item->title;
        $link = $item->link;
        $published_on = $item->pubDate;
        $description = $item->description;
        echo '<p class="rss-feed"><a href="'.$link.'">'.$title.'</a></p>';
        echo '<p>'.$description.'</p>';
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to limit the number of items displayed you can use the [array_slice](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php) function to store a subset of the retrieved values in `$items`, e.g. change:

```
$items = $rss->channel->item;
```

to:

```
$items = array_slice($rss->channel->item, 0, 5);
```

If you want to change the number of items fetched from the URL then you need to check whether/how this URL supports this behaviour.